# Fetch MySQL multiple row data and show in individual text box

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

[image]I am trying to get the `StudentFirstName` from data base and show in the text box right now am using grid view where it shows the data but not in textbox am not sure how to get all the data from data base and show in individual text box.

MyDB

```
    StudentFirstName    SchoolID      StudCourse
    abc                  sc123         A
    cef                  sc155         A
    gij                  sc133         A
    abc                  sc122         B
    cef                  sc156         B
    gij                  sc144         B
```

C#

```
                     using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string oString = "Select StudentFirstName from student WHERE StudCourse=@DDSelected_Class  order by StudentFirstName  ASC";
            MySqlCommand oCmd = new MySqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
            oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DDSelected_Class", DDSelected_Class);

            myConnection.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                if (oReader == null || !oReader.HasRows)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('No Student Found')", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    while (oReader.Read())
                    {
                        GridView1.DataSource = oReader;
                        GridView1.DataBind();


                    }

                }
                myConnection.Close();
            }               
        }
```

Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you want to show all the student first names in each individual textboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define `ItemTemplate` for your column. It will contain a `textbox` and the field name name in `Eval` to bind it.

**Complete code sample:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Names">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentFirstName ") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    <Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Exactly was expecting the same i need one more help ??

Comment: there is one row with text box and one more with the data base fetch how to stop that

Comment: With the code I provided, there must not be another row. Can you please share an screenshot?

Comment: You just need to set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`, it is generating your columns by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98307/discussion-between-shaik-and-shaharyar).

Comment: Worked Thanks i think you are the perfect person to help me if u dont mind can you help on how to save them back to data base if u want i can ask one more question

Comment: I have posted a new question hear :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350032/save-grid-view-textbox-data-to-database