# Save Grid View Textbox Data to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]I am trying to save grid view text box value and two other text box that are filled by user that are `Total Marks` and `Marks Scored` to data base am not sure how to pass back the values of that textboxs to data base on one click of submit

DB where the value to be saved are

```
Studentname     RegNo     TotalMarks   Marksscored
 asdsa            22        125           22
```

My Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Names">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStudent_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentFirstName") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Register Number">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtreg_number" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentRegID") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Marks">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txttotal_marks" runat="server" Text='' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Marks Scored">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtmarks_scored" runat="server" Text='' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 GridView1.Visible = true;
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
 for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
 TextBox txtUsrId=(TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Your textbox id");
 string UserID = txtUsrId.Text;
 string q="insert into details (name) values('"+UserID+"')";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 da.Fill(dt);
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the ans but i dont know how to modify to my gridview can you plz help me on that

Comment: I tried this code by adding my Grid View Textbox id that gives me some error i shell i upload the screen shot ??

Comment: I have uploaded a screen shot